# How to debug an IntelliJ plugin in a different platform (eg. Pycharm)

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I have a license for PyCharm Professional and am using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition to develop a plugin for it. I need to run the plugin in PyCharm to test it out. I can't use the Python plugin for IntelliJ IDEA to test it as only the Community edition of the plugin appears to be available for me. If I manually download the professional version and try to install it I get `Plugin 'Python' is incompatible with this installation`. I assume I would need IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate to be able to use the professional version of the Python plugin.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204453/debugging-plugins-in-intellij-and-pycharm), which suggests it is possible to use PyCharm as the target for a "Plugin" run configuration, but I haven't had any luck following those steps. I set the JRE to `/opt/pycharm-professional/jre64` but got `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.idea.Main`. I then grabbed the java command line args from a running instance of PyCharm and added those in (particularly the classpath) but got `Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2`. I haven't been able to find anything in the docs on how to set this up.

Comment: Point your SDK to Pycharm, not JRE. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37046421/685796

Comment: That gives me `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.idea.Main`, as described in the question.

Comment: Specifically, I go into Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> Module SDK, hit "New..." and point it at "/opt/pycharm-professional". That creates an SDK called "PyCharm PY-172.3757.67" and selects it, and the project builds successfully. If I then run the "Plugin" configuration I get the error above.

Comment: Are you using `Default` JRE in your Run Configuration?